# how to display the key name which is dynamic to html

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

Here I have a mongo collection like

```
"dashboard" : {
    "todo" : {
        "_id" : "GdfaHPoT7FXW78awi",
        "_maxCount" : "1",
       "_title" : "todo",

    }
    "task" : {
        "_id" : "GdfaHPoT7FXW78awi",
        "_maxCount" : "1",
       "_title" : "task",

    }
}
```

here task and todo are dynamic field names, I have looped the dashboard in an ng-repeat. 
Now I want to know how to display details inside dashboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go through it

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.dashboard = {
    "todo" : {
      "_id" : "GdfaHPoT7FXW78awi",
      "_maxCount" : "1",
     "_title" : "todo"
    }, 
    "task" : {
      "_id" : "GdfaHPoT7FXW78awi",
      "_maxCount" : "1",
     "_title" : "task",
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="(itemName, item) in dashboard">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-head bg-info">{{itemName}}</div>
      <div class="panel-body">{{item._title}}&nbsp;{{item._maxCount}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in dashboard">
  {{key1}}
  <div ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value1">
      {{key2}}: {{value2}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: task and todo are dynamic here... that objects may be there or may not be!!  so you are not sure how many keys will be there, 1,2,3 etc...

Comment: Yes, and it should work with what I posted, you gave it a try ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you assign dynamic field name "todo" which is a string to a variable var1

you can access _maxCount of some docX as :

```
docX["dashboard"][var1]["_maxCount"]
```

Comment: Please can you expand your answer